# How pass data from second window to main?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt

I have a python app that change mac address with pyqt5 GUI. I have two python files. The main python file (mainWindow.py) that run main program then I press button to open the second window from second python file secondWindow.py. In second python file opens a window entry then I have to put letters and numbers like  then I have to pass data in the first main app label window.

Can anyone help me to solve that?

I tried to reduce code.

mainWindow.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import os
import sys
import subprocess


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from secondWindow import Ui_macSpecific


import macspoof_bash
import settings
macspoof_bash.write_to_ini()

# Read and write settings in macspoof.ini file
from configparser import ConfigParser

# instantiate
config = ConfigParser()

# parse existing file
config.read('/home/user/.config/macspoof/macspoof.ini')

# read values from a section
wired = config.get('ethernet', 'wired')
wireless = config.get('wifi', 'wireless')

   class Ui_MainWindow(object):

    def specificWindow(self):
        self.window = QtWidgets.QDialog()
        self.ui = Ui_macSpecific()
        #self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
        self.ui.setupUi(self.window, self) # <--- assign MainWindow as parent to second window
        self.window.show()

    def aboutWindow(self):
        self.aboutWindow = QtWidgets.QDialog()
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.aboutWindow)
        self.aboutWindow.show()

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(480, 400)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(36, 31, 49);\n"
"font: 11pt \"DejaVu Sans\";\n"
"color: rgb(246, 245, 244);")
        self.label_3.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter) 
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_3, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget, clicked = lambda: self.specificWindow())
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_6.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_6.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("DejaVu Sans")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.pushButton_6.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_6.setObjectName("pushButton_6")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_6, 4, 1, 1, 1)

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget, clicked = lambda: self.button_vendor_wired())

        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("DejaVu Sans")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 2, 0, 1, 1)

        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget, clicked = lambda: self.button_fully_wired())

        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_3.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_3.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("DejaVu Sans")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.pushButton_3.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_3, 3, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_8 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget, clicked = lambda: self.button_original_wireless())
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_8.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_8.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("DejaVu Sans")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.pushButton_8.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_8.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.pushButton_8.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.pushButton_8.setObjectName("pushButton_8")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_8, 5, 1, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget, clicked = lambda: self.button_vendor_wireless())
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_2.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_2.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("DejaVu Sans")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.pushButton_2.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2, 2, 1, 1, 1)

        self.pushButton_7 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget, clicked = lambda: self.button_original_wired())

        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_7.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_7.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("DejaVu Sans")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.pushButton_7.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_7.setObjectName("pushButton_7")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_7, 5, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget, clicked = lambda: self.specificWindow())
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_5.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_5.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("DejaVu Sans")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.pushButton_5.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_5, 4, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_4.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(36, 31, 49);\n"
"font: 11pt \"DejaVu Sans\";\n"
"color: rgb(246, 245, 244);")
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")

        self.label_4.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter) 

        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_4, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget, clicked = lambda: self.button_fully_wireless())
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_4.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_4.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("DejaVu Sans")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.pushButton_4.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_4, 3, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
        self.label.setSizeIncrement(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(36, 31, 49);\n"
"font: 11pt \"DejaVu Sans\";\n"
"color: rgb(246, 245, 244);")
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter) 
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(36, 31, 49);\n"
"font: 11pt \"DejaVu Sans\";\n"
"color: rgb(246, 245, 244);")
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")

        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_2, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 480, 20))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuFile = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuFile.setObjectName("menuFile")
        self.menuEdit = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuEdit.setObjectName("menuEdit")
        self.menuHelp = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuHelp.setObjectName("menuHelp")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.actionExit = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)

        self.actionExit.triggered.connect(lambda: self.close_window())

        self.actionExit.setObjectName("actionExit")
        self.actionPreferences = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionPreferences.setObjectName("actionPreferences")
        self.actionAbout = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)

        self.actionAbout.triggered.connect(lambda: self.aboutWindow())


        self.actionAbout.setObjectName("actionAbout")
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionExit)
        self.menuEdit.addAction(self.actionPreferences)
        self.menuHelp.addAction(self.actionAbout)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuFile.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuEdit.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuHelp.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

        self.update_wired_label(MainWindow)
        self.update_wired_mac_address_label(MainWindow)
        self.update_wireless_label(MainWindow)
        self.update_wireless_mac_address_label(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MAC address spoofing"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.pushButton_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Set the MAC"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Don\'t change vendor bytes"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Set fully random MAC"))
        self.pushButton_8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Reset MAC address to its original"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Don\'t change vendor bytes"))
        self.pushButton_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Reset MAC address to its original"))
        self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Set the MAC"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Set fully random MAC"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.menuFile.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "File"))
        self.menuEdit.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Settings"))
        self.menuHelp.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Help"))
        self.actionExit.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Exit"))
        self.actionPreferences.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Preferences"))
        self.actionAbout.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "About"))

    def update_wired_label(self, MainWindow):
        print('update_wired_label')
        self.wired = config.get('ethernet', 'wired')
        self.label.setText(str(self.wired))

    def update_wired_mac_address_label(self, MainWindow):
        print('update_wired_mac_address_label')
        config.read('/home/user/.config/macspoof/macspoof.ini')
        self.wired_mac_address = config.get('ethernet', 'wired_mac_address')
        self.label_3.setText(str(self.wired_mac_address))

    def update_wireless_label(self, MainWindow):
        print('update_wireless_label')
        self.wireless = config.get('wifi', 'wireless')
        self.label_2.setText(str(self.wireless))

    def update_wireless_mac_address_label(self, MainWindow):
        print('update_wireless_mac_address_label')
        config.read('/home/user/.config/macspoof/macspoof.ini')
        self.wireless_mac_address = config.get('wifi', 'wireless_mac_address')
        self.label_4.setText(str(self.wireless_mac_address))

    def button_vendor_wired(self):
        print('vendor_wired')
        subprocess.run(['macchanger', '-e', wired])
        macspoof_bash.vendor_wired()
        self.update_wired_mac_address_label(MainWindow)

    def button_fully_wired(self):
        print('fully wired')
        subprocess.run(['macchanger', '-r', wired])
        macspoof_bash.write_to_ini()
        self.update_wired_mac_address_label(MainWindow)

    #def button_specific_wired(self):
     #   print('specific wired')
     #   subprocess.run(["macchanger", "-m", wired])

    def button_original_wired(self):
        print('original wired')
        subprocess.run(['macchanger', '-p', wired])
        macspoof_bash.write_to_ini()
        self.update_wired_mac_address_label(MainWindow)

    def button_vendor_wireless(self):
        print('vendor_wireless')
        subprocess.run(['macchanger', '-e', wireless])
        macspoof_bash.vendor_wireless()
        self.update_wireless_mac_address_label(MainWindow)

    def button_fully_wireless(self):
        print('fully wireless')
        #wireless = config.get("wifi", "wireless")
        #subprocess.run(['macchanger', '-r', wired])
        macspoof_bash.fully_wireless()
        self.update_wireless_mac_address_label(MainWindow)

    def button_specific_wireless(self):
        print('specific wired')
        subprocess.run(["macchanger", "-m", wireless])

    def button_original_wireless(self):
        print('original wireless')
        subprocess.run(['macchanger', '-p', wireless])
        macspoof_bash.write_to_ini()
        self.update_wireless_mac_address_label(MainWindow)


    def close_window(self):
        print("Quit")
        sys.exit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

secondWindow.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

# Read and write settings in macspoof.ini file
from configparser import ConfigParser

# instantiate
config = ConfigParser()

# parse existing file
config.read('macspoof.ini')

# read values from a section
wired = config.get('ethernet', 'wired')
wired_mac_address = config.get('ethernet', 'wired_mac_address')


class Ui_macSpecific(object):
    def setupUi(self, macSpecific, parent):  # <--- add extra parameter parent
        self.parent = parent  # < --- create new attribute parent

    #def setupUi(self, macSpecific):
        macSpecific.setObjectName("macSpecific")
        macSpecific.resize(301, 140)
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(macSpecific)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(macSpecific)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("DejaVu Sans")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(macSpecific)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.lineEdit.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.lineEdit.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("DejaVu Sans")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.lineEdit.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.lineEdit.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.lineEdit.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(macSpecific, clicked = lambda: self.submit())


        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 2, 0, 1, 1)

        self.retranslateUi(macSpecific)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(macSpecific)

    def retranslateUi(self, macSpecific):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        macSpecific.setWindowTitle(_translate("macSpecific", "MAC address spoofing"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("macSpecific", "Enter A MAC address"))
        self.lineEdit.setText(_translate("macSpecific", "11:22:33:44:55:66"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("macSpecific", "Submit"))

    def submit(self):
        print("submit")
        #self.parent.label_3.setText(str(self.wired_mac_address))  # use parent to set label text
        self.parent.label_3.setText(str(self.parent.wired_mac_address)) # <-----Try this then.




if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    macSpecific = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_macSpecific()
    ui.setupUi(macSpecific)
    macSpecific.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to assign the MainWindow as the parent of the SecondWindow.  Then to get the label text all the SecondWindow has to do is `self.parent.label.setText('something')`.  See the minor adjustments I made below.

`mainWindow.py`

```py
class Ui_MainWindow(object):

    def specificWindow(self):
        self.window = QtWidgets.QDialog()
        self.ui = Ui_macSpecific()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.window, self) # <--- assign MainWindow as parent to second window
        self.window.show()
```

`secondWindow.py`

```py
import macspoof_bash

class Ui_macSpecific(object):
    def setupUi(self, macSpecific, master):
        self.master = master
        self.window = macSpecific
        macSpecific.setObjectName("macSpecific")
        macSpecific.resize(301, 140)
        ...
        ...
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(macSpecific, clicked = lambda: self.submit())
        
            
    def submit(self):
        print("submit")
        text = self.lineEdit.text()
        self.master.label_3.setText(text) 
        self.window.close()
        config['ethernet']['wired_mac_address'] = text
        with open("macspoof.ini", "w") as inifile:
            config.write(inifile)
```

Comment: It shows the error message `AttributeError: 'Ui_macSpecific' object has no attribute 'wired_mac_address'`

Comment: I tried to reduce code. I declare the mainwindow.py. Thank you!!

Comment: I filled all code. I hope to help you!

Comment: It erases text label. Don't pass data! It also don't close the window after press submit.